# Custom SharePoint 2010 mobile login screen

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So our issue is with the MOBILE login form in SharePoint 2010. We have FBA implemented and it works great for non-mobile users.  It is a custom login that lets users switch between AD or FBA.  But the issue arises with Mobiles (iPhone, Blackberry, Win Mobile, Android) when they hit the site.

How can I customize the mobile login screen for a sharepoint 2010 site? Has anyone done this?

**Edit 1:**
The default behavior of the mobile login screen is oddly only allowing the FBA users to login and not the A/D users.

**Edit 2:**
I know that my iPad works fine in Sharepoint 2010 using my A/D account on a custom login form. The problem arises when I go to the iPhone. So what you are saying is that the mobile login screen only supports FBA for a reason, A/D accounts won't work?

**Edit 3:**
We tested on windows phone 7 and it does support the standard login and does not automatically redirect to the mobile page. So Win Phone 7 is a non-issue. The main issue is iPhone and Android since they goes to the mobile login which is currently only supporting FBA users. Our custom non-mobile login form we created automatically handles A/D login based on custom code we wrote. Ideally we'd like to have mobile point to the custom login page we built. But we can't find how this is set.

Comment: The default behavior of the mobile login screen is oddly only allowing the FBA users to login and not the A/D users.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefits of others facing similar problem, here is our alternative.

In SharePoint 2013 Application Management, highlight your Web Application and select Authentication Providers. Select FBA and in the Custom Sign In Page and append "?mobile=0" to your FBA URL like this:

[image: SP central administration]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create custom login screen.

Follow the steps below to open your web app. on Mobiles (iPhone, Blackberry, Win Mobile, Android)

1. Navigate to Inetpub (in default drive (generally c))
2. Navigate further to wwwroot\ws\virtualdirectories
3. Navigate to your application folder (port number specific)
4. Navigate to App_Browsers folder
5. Open compact.browser in notepad
6. **Find "Iphone" or any other device for which you want your app**. As result you will get to XML tag for **iphone safari browser**, see the sample below :

1. set the value false in following element :

likewise there is XML browser tag for each mobile device (android, BlackBerry, etc), just change the value of isMobileDevice to false

hope it helps
-- Sumit (courtesy Ishaan )